# HUE operation timed out for hive queries

Tags: hue

There is a operation timed out error whenever we are firing a hive query through hue (4.3.0).
Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 0):

You Can solve this issue in 2ways:

1. Restart HS2 and try executing Hue query --->Can be a temporary fix
2. Check "HiveServer2 and Impala Thrift Connection Timeout" in Hue and set the timeout value in hours and restart Hue, will fix this issue.